# Is there a "one-liner" way to get a list of keys from a dictionary in sorted order?

Tags: python, iterator, syntactic-sugar

The list `sort()` method is a modifier function that returns `None`.

So if I want to iterate through all of the keys in a dictionary I cannot do:

```
for k in somedictionary.keys().sort():
    dosomething()
```

Instead, I must:

```
keys = somedictionary.keys()
keys.sort()
for k in keys:
    dosomething()
```

Is there a pretty way to iterate through these keys in sorted order without having to break it up in to multiple steps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for k in sorted(somedictionary.keys()):
    doSomething(k)
```

Note that you can also get all of the keys and values sorted by keys like this:

```
for k, v in sorted(somedictionary.iteritems()):
   doSomething(k, v)
```

Answer (score 8):

Can I answer my own question?

I have just discovered the handy function "sorted" which does exactly what I was looking for.

```
for k in sorted(somedictionary.keys()):
    dosomething()
```

It shows up in [Python 2.5 dictionary 2 key sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157424/python-25-dictionary-2-key-sort)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, .keys() is not necessary:

```
for k in sorted(somedictionary):
    doSomething(k)
```

or

```
[doSomethinc(k) for k in sorted(somedict)]
```