# How do I sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?

Tags: python, list, sorting, reverse

I have a list of Python objects that I want to sort by a specific attribute of each object:

```
[Tag(name="toe", count=10), Tag(name="leg", count=2), ...]
```

How do I sort the list by `.count` in descending order?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157424/python-2-5-dictionary-2-key-sort, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222752/sorting-a-tuple-that-contains-tuples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327191/in-python-is-there-a-one-line-pythonic-way-to-get-a-list-of-keys-from-a-dictiona

Comment: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for those who are looking for more info about sorting in Python.

Comment: apart from operator.attrgetter('attribute_name') you can also use functors as key like object_list.sort(key=my_sorting_functor('my_key')), leaving the implementation out intentionally.

Answer (score 1953, accepted):

To sort the list in place:

```
orig_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
```

To return a new list, use `sorted`:

```
new_list = sorted(orig_list, key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
```

Explanation:

- `key=lambda x: x.count` sorts by count.
- `reverse=True` sorts in descending order.

More on [sorting by keys](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys).

Comment: No problem. btw, if muhuk is right and it's a list of Django objects, you should consider his solution. However, for the general case of sorting objects, my solution is probably best practice.

Comment: On large lists you will get better performance using operator.attrgetter('count') as your key. This is just an optimized (lower level) form of the lambda function in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. In case if it is a list of dictionaries and 'count' is one of its key then it needs to be changed like below : ut.sort(key=lambda x: x['count'], reverse=True)

Comment: I suppose it deserves the following update: if there is a need to sort by multiple fields, it could be achieved by consecutive calls to sort(), because python is using stable sort algorithm.

Comment: I am receiving this error, can someone add in answer how to resolve it? ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I'm trying to use this technique for a dt object but getting an error. 
Code: events_2.sort(key=lambda x: x['DTSTART'].dt, reverse=True). Error: TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes. Any ideas?

Comment: @peetysmith it looks like youre 'DTSTART' column contains more than one date type (offset-naive and offset-aware). You need to first convert that column to use the same type, before the sort function can use it.

Comment: Thanks @KenanBanks, you were right. Annoyingly outlook was doing some weird things with calendar timezones so that some came through without the timezone details... no idea why!

Answer (score 118):

A way that can be fastest, especially if your list has a lot of records, is to use `operator.attrgetter("count")`. However, this might run on an pre-operator version of Python, so it would be nice to have a fallback mechanism. You might want to do the following, then:

```
try: import operator
except ImportError: keyfun= lambda x: x.count # use a lambda if no operator module
else: keyfun= operator.attrgetter("count") # use operator since it's faster than lambda

ut.sort(key=keyfun, reverse=True) # sort in-place
```

Comment: Here I would use the variable name "keyfun" instead of "cmpfun" to avoid confusion. The sort() method does accept a comparison function through the cmp= argument as well.

Comment: This doesn't seems to work if the object has dynamically added attributes, (if you've done `self.__dict__ = {'some':'dict'}` after the `__init__` method). I don't know why it sould be different, though.

Comment: @tutuca: I've never replaced the instance `__dict__`. Note that "an object having dynamically added attributes" and "setting an object's `__dict__` attribute" are almost orthogonal concepts. I'm saying that because your comment seems to imply that setting the `__dict__` attribute is a requirement for dynamically adding attributes.

Comment: @tzot: I'm looking right at this: https://github.com/stochastic-technologies/goatfish/blob/master/goatfish/models.py#L168 and using that iterator here: https://github.com/TallerTechnologies/dishey/blob/master/app.py#L28 raises attribute error. Maybe because of python3, but still...

Comment: @tutuca: I would do `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` instead of `self.__dict__= kwargs`. In any case, perhaps it's a Python 3 issue, since 2.7.3 seems to [run it ok](http://pastebin.com/iWRfz2Cu). I will investigate with Python 3 some time later.

Comment: And then there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137772/#comment-2078476), which could suggest it's the class Model's metaclass that's at fault here.

Comment: @tzot, it's not django related, the goatfish Meta attribute is just a raw object with no magic whatsoever... 
I've tested it in a python 2.7 project and seems to work as expected. I'll need to read further on the issue...

Comment: @tzot: if I understand the use of `operator.attrgetter`, I could supply a function with any property name and return a sorted collection.

Comment: For those looking for more info: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Operator_Module_Functions

Answer (score 99):

Readers should notice that the key= method:

```
ut.sort(key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
```

is many times faster than adding rich comparison operators to the objects. I was surprised to read this (page 485 of "Python in a Nutshell"). You can confirm this by running tests on this little program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

class C:
    def __init__(self,count):
        self.count = count

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return cmp(self.count,other.count)

longList = [C(random.random()) for i in xrange(1000000)] #about 6.1 secs
longList2 = longList[:]

longList.sort() #about 52 - 6.1 = 46 secs
longList2.sort(key = lambda c: c.count) #about 9 - 6.1 = 3 secs
```

My, very minimal, tests show the first sort is more than 10 times slower, but the book says it is only about 5 times slower in general. The reason they say is due to the highly optimizes sort algorithm used in python (**timsort**).

Still, its very odd that .sort(lambda) is faster than plain old .sort(). I hope they fix that.

Comment: Defining `__cmp__` is equivalent to calling `.sort(cmp=lambda)`, not `.sort(key=lambda)`, so it isn't odd at all.

Comment: @tzot is exactly right. The first sort has to compare objects against each other again and again. The second sort accesses each object only once to extract its count value, and then it performs a simple numerical sort which is highly optimized. A more fair comparison would be `longList2.sort(cmp = cmp)`. I tried this out and it performed nearly the same as `.sort()`. (Also: note that the "cmp" sort parameter was removed in Python 3.)

Comment: __cmp__ was deprecated in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter

Answer (score 84):

**Object-oriented approach**

It's good practice to make object sorting logic, if applicable, a property of the class rather than incorporated in each instance the ordering is required.

This ensures consistency and removes the need for boilerplate code.

At a minimum, you should specify `__eq__` and `__lt__` operations for this to work. Then just use `sorted(list_of_objects)`.

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank < other.rank

hand = [Card(10, 'H'), Card(2, 'h'), Card(12, 'h'), Card(13, 'h'), Card(14, 'h')]
hand_order = [c.rank for c in hand]  # [10, 2, 12, 13, 14]

hand_sorted = sorted(hand)
hand_sorted_order = [c.rank for c in hand_sorted]  # [2, 10, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Could you point us to some documentation that elaborates on why `__eq__` and `__lt__` are the minimum implementation requirements?

Comment: @FriendFX, I believe it's implied by [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends): `•The sort routines are guaranteed to use __lt__() when making comparisons between two objects...`

Comment: @FriendFX: See https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html for Comparison and Sorting

Comment: is there any way to automatically forward all special binary comparison methods to one attribute of the class instead of implementing `__eq__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__` and `__ne__` and inside just forward to the attributes special function?

Comment: I just wrote my own decorator to accomplish what I wanted in the previous comment. it's really ugly.mbetter implement `__eq__` and `__lt__` and then use `@functools.total_ordering` to get the rest.

Comment: While implementing rich comparisons into the object definition like this is very elegant, it is much slower than using passing a key like in the top answer. I did a [little benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78025707/19123103) to which illustrates this.

Answer (score 47):

```
from operator import attrgetter
ut.sort(key = attrgetter('count'), reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 18):

It looks much like a list of Django ORM model instances.

Why not sort them on query like this:

```
ut = Tag.objects.order_by('-count')
```

Comment: It is, but using django-tagging, so I was using a built-in for grabbing a Tag set by usage for a particular query set, like so:

Tag.objects.usage_for_queryset(QuerySet, counts=True)

Answer (score 16):

If the attribute you want to sort by is a *property*, then you can avoid importing `operator.attrgetter` and use the property's [`fget`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) method instead.

For example, for a class `Circle` with a property `radius` we could sort a list of `circles` by radii as follows:

```
result = sorted(circles, key=Circle.radius.fget)
```

This is not the most well-known feature but often saves me a line with the import.

Comment: I was surprised I couldn't just put `Circle.radius`. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Thanks for the pointer of using `fget`. I don't like defining lambdas if something else can do the job, and I don't like passing names of attributes as strings to `attrgetter`, it just feels wrong, to me.

Comment: @PeterWood The key needs to (1) be callable, (2) accept one argument, and (3) return a value which is sortable. `sorted` takes each item to be sorted, passes each of them in turn to the key, and sorts the values returned as proxies for the items themselves. `Circle.radius` doesn't work because `property` objects themselves aren't callable.  But they do have an attribute called `fget` which is.

Comment: @ibonyun thanks, that really helps clarify why

Answer (score 14):

Add rich comparison operators to the object class, then use sort() method of the list.
See [rich comparison in python](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

---

**Update**: Although this method would work, I think solution from Triptych is better suited to your case because way simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Also if someone wants to sort list that contains strings and numbers for e.g.

```
 eglist=[
     "some0thing3",
     "some0thing2",
     "some1thing2",
     "some1thing0",
     "some3thing10",
     "some3thing2",
     "some1thing1",
     "some0thing1"]
```

Then here is the code for that:

```
import re

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

eglist=[
         "some0thing3",
         "some0thing2",
         "some1thing2",
         "some1thing0",
         "some3thing10",
         "some3thing2",
         "some1thing1",
         "some0thing1"
]

eglist.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(eglist)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jose M Vidal's answer mentions something important: using rich comparisons (`__lt__`, `__eq__` etc. as in @jpp's answer) makes sorting much slower than passing a key function (as in the accepted answer). However, they end up showing a test using `__cmp__` method which doesn't exist in Python 3 (which tbf was indeed so much slower than passing key in Python 2).

I want to point out that even in Python 3.12.0, using rich comparisons as in @jpp's answer makes sorting much slower than passing a key function.

The results of a little timeit test is shown below where sorting using rich comparisons vs a lambda key function vs `operator.attrgetter` as key are compared. For a list with 10k items, it took about 18.8 ms when rich comparisons were used whereas it took 2.93 ms when a lambda key function was used and 2.47 ms when `operator.attrgetter` was used.

So, as @tzot mentioned, `operator.attrgetter` is faster than a lambda; however, using a key function in the first place instead of rich comparisons makes sorting over 5 times faster.

```py
import timeit
import random
from operator import attrgetter

class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank):
        self.rank = rank

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.rank == other.rank

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank < other.rank

n = 100
random.seed(0)
lst = [Card(random.randrange(10000)) for _ in range(10000)]


min(timeit.repeat(lambda: sorted(lst), number=n))/n
# 0.018813106999732553

min(timeit.repeat(lambda: sorted(lst, key=lambda card: card.rank), number=n))/n
# 0.0029304770001908763

min(timeit.repeat(lambda: sorted(lst, key=attrgetter('rank')), number=n))/n
# 0.00247172600007616
```