# Change class instance inside an instance method

Tags: python, class, instance, hotswap

Any idea if there is a way to make the following code to work

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def changeme(self):
        self = Test(3)

t = Test(1)
assert t.var == 1
t.changeme()
assert t.var == 3
```

is something like the following safe to use for more complex objects (like django models, to hot swap the db entry the instance is referring to)

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def changeme(self):
        new_instance = Test(3)
        self.__dict__ = new_instance.__dict__

t = Test(1)
assert t.var == 1
t.changeme()
assert t.var == 3
```

Comment: Why? You clearly want a new instance, why not just make a new instance and throw this one away? Explain the usecase, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self = Test(3)` is re-binding the local name `self`, with no externally observable effects.

Assigning `self.__dict__` (unless you're talking about instances with `__slots__` or from classes with non-trivial metaclasses) is usually OK, and so is `self.__init__(3)` to re-initialize the instance.  However I'd prefer to have a specific method `self.restart(3)` which **knows** it's being called on an already-initialized instance and does whatever's needed to cater for that specific and unusual case.

Comment: Django's model metaclasses are... messy. I wouldn't be surprised if trying to reassign `self.__dict__` blew up spectacularly.

Comment: @Ignacio, with "non-trivial metaclasses" in play (or `__slots__`, etc), you may want to use a loop of `getattr`/`setattr` instead. The advantage of writing the `restart` method I advocate is that you isolate there the tweaking (if any) needed to support various cases, from normal objects to ones with messy metaclasses and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

No, and no.

Having said that, you *can* change the *class*, but don't do that either.

Answer (score 2):

The former code works, except it won't do much, seeing as it just replaces the object named 'self' within the scope of changeme(). Python names aren't locked to values, they are always relative to their scope or namespace.

To do what you want you'd need to have access to a name outside the class, which you could assign to from within it:

```
class Test:
  def changeme(self):
    global myclass
    myclass = Test(3)

myclass = Test(2)
myclass.changeme()
print myclass # 3
```

This basically just overwrites the name 'myclass' to point to the new instance. It doesn't "overwrite" the first instance like you might think. The old instance still lives, and will be garbage collected unless referenced elsewhere.