# Python Copying: Copy First Item, Then Append Others

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have two scripts, one where a class is created and a second loading/plotting script. I have three instances of the same class (`T1`, `T2`, and `T3`) but want to combine them into a single `T`. When do `T=T1`, then `T+T2` and `T+T3`, `T1` inherits the `T2` and `T3` instances when I only want `T` to have all the instances.

I tried modifying my `__add__` magic method in my class script as below but the `deepcopy` doesn't work. The `T` continues to be empty. However when I do `T = deepcopy(T1)` in my command window, it works fine. I'd prefer the `__add__` method to include this capability.

From class script:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    """ A "magic" method to overload the '+' operator by
    appending trajectories.
    """
    if len(self.contents) == 0:
        self = deepcopy(other)
    else:
        self.contents.append(other)
```

I also tried created a new method to directly do the deepcopy, but it also will not copy as expected.

```
def copy(self,other):
    self = deepcopy(other)
```

I start with `T` empty:

```
In [80]: T.contents
Out[80]: []
```

But I want `T` to include `T1` through `T3` without `T1` being identical to `T`.

```
In [74]: T.contents
Out[74]: 
[Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_2D2M_RODupdate
        contains data from FAST,
 Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_1D2M_RODupdate
        contains data from FAST,
 Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_2D3M
        contains data from FAST]
```

Not:

```
In [74]: T1.contents
Out[74]: 
[Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_2D2M_RODupdate
        contains data from FAST,
 Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_1D2M_RODupdate
        contains data from FAST,
 Trajectory Object: MONTE_RUN_mmv13_2D3M
        contains data from FAST]
```

Comment: I don't believe `self = deepcopy(other)` actually makes any change to the object. It merely changes what the local name "self" points to. Once the function ends, it's effectively forgotten. In any case, shouldn't `__add__` return a brand new object, rather than modifying the existing one? It's not like `a+b` modifies `a` when a and b are integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137772/change-class-instance-inside-an-instance-method