# Sorting thru a cell collection in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am reading in an xlsx file, like so,

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheets['DATA'])
allCells = sheet.get_cell_collection()
print allCells
```

allCells is an unordered list of openpyxl.cell.Cell objects. allCells looks like,

```
[<Cell Data.B4>, <Cell Data.A6>, <Cell Data.B6>, <Cell Data.A1>, <Cell Data.B5>, <Cell Data.A3>, <Cell Data.A2>, <Cell Data.A5>, <Cell Data.B1>, <Cell Data.B2>]
```

I want to sort this list by column and then by row indices. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Use COM and forget openpyxl, that's what I've done. http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/

Comment: Do you want to sort them by value or row&column indices?

Comment: I want to sort them by indices

Comment: What is an unordered list in Python? Are you referring to a `set` object? Or just that `allCells` *is* actually `list`, it just isn't guaranteed to be in any particular order?

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be of particular order as returned by openpyxl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get row and column information for every cell in the list like so:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.workbook.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
a=ws.cell('D6')
a.row
6
a.column
'D'
```

Now it's just a matter to sort the lot according to any criteria that you desire. [Here's](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216689/sorting-algorithms-in-python) a list of different algorithms to be used for sorting. And this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-in-python-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects) describes how to sort a list according to objects' attributes. What is the problem? I'll edit the answer accordingly.