# Sort a list of objects in python by the sum of some attributes

Tags: python, list, sorting, attributes

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-in-python-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects) rather helpful in the past, but this time I need to sort some objects in a list by the sum of some of their attributes.

Specifically, I have a list of objects each with a dimensions atttribute on 3 axes (eg: obj.dimensions.x)

I know you can sort a list by one attribute with:

```
list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.dimensions.x)
```

But how could I sort it by the sum of the dimensions of each object's three axes such that an object with dimensions 3,3,3 would come before an object with 5,1,1 (greater sum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `obj` in your example is your entire object, you can do this:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.dimensions.x+obj.dimensions.y+obj.dimensions.z)
```

`list` is a poor name for a variable, since its also a name of the built-in `list()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.dimensions.x + obj.dimensions.y + obj.dimensions.z)

>>> l = [[5,1,1], [3,3,3], [2,1,1], [0,0,0]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2])
>>> l
[[0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]]
```

This is just an example to show you that you have an access to the item of a list in key function (FYI, in my example  `l.sort(key=sum)` would be more appropriate).