# How to sort a list of words by length

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I want to sort words in a list based on length.

The test case is `{'cat','jump','blue','balloon'}`

When run through this method it will print something along the lines of:

```
{'balloon','jump','blue','balloon'}
```

Another problem I have run into, is that the type of python we were using worked fine, however when I try to run the .py in the Python 3.5.2 shell, it comes up with errors.

I mainly just need to know what I did wrong, and what I can do to fix it so that it works. Any help is appreciated!

The .py file can be found [here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qZYcl-qhFmQVBUSmxKUmx3eE0/view?usp=sharing)

```
def wordSort():
    words = []
    minimum = 'NaN'
    index = 0
    x = 0    
    y = 0    
    z = 1
    #How many words to be entered
    length = input('How many words would you like to enter? ')
    #Put words in the number of times you entered previously    
    while not z >= length + 1:
        words.append(raw_input('Enter word #' + str(z) + ': '))
        z += 1
    while x < length:
        minimum = words[x]
        #Goes through the list and finds a smaller word
        while y < length:
            if len(words[y]) < len(minimum):
                minimum = words[y]
                index = y
            y += 1
        words[index] = words[x]
        words[x] = minimum
        x += 1
    print words
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of objects , based on an attribute of the objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: This is python 2.x (presumably 2.7) code. It needs to either be run under python 2.x or adjusted for python 3.

Answer (score 7):

- `print` is a function in Python 3.5 and needs to be used as `print(words)`. Read more about it [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function)
- Given a list of words this can be used to sort them according to length of string using [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

  `sorted(word_list , key = len)`

Comment: even better: `sorted(word_list, key=len)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will sort the list based on length of strings in ascending order

```
list_name.sort(key=len)
```

For descending order,

```
list_name.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
```