# How to insert elements of a list into another list depending on date value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of homes :

```
list1 = [home1, home2, home3, home4]
```

and I have another list of specific homes:

```
list2 = [ home6, home7, home8, home10]
```

Every home has a field `date` .I want to insert `List2` into `list1` depending on 
 `home.date`

For example if `home7.date < home1.date`, so  `home7` will be inserted into `list1` before `home1`

I tried to use two for loops but it seems to be very slow and there are many calculations done by the CPU

```
        for el in list1:
            for elt2 in list2:
                if el.date > elt2.date:
                    list1.insert((list1.index(el)),elt2)
```

**PS** : some dates are not set so they have a `None` value and I don't want to change the index of  corresponded `home` in `list1`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code doesn't currently handle the case where a `Home.date` would be `None`.

Answer (score 8):

First thing first: modifying a list (or dict, set etc) while iterating over it is usually a very bad idea.

In your case, the simplest solution is probably to just merge the two lists first then sort the list using the `key` callback:

```
list1.extend(list2)
list1.sort(key=lambda x: x.date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.. the problem is that some `x.date` are `None`   and I don't want to change their indexes . I will update my post

Comment: @pietà this is a much more complex problem - and one your current code does not handle actually (you'd get `TypeError` exceptions trying to compare a `date` with `None`).

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

```
list3 = (list1 + list2)
list3.sort(key = lambda x: x.date)
```

Comment: Will need to provide the key for sorting

Comment: @ShreyasG, using `.sort()` will return `None` because it happens in-place.  It should be `sorted(list1+list2)`.

Comment: Right, agree with both of you. Didn't check the syntax and forgot the key to sort.

Comment: Actually, I would use `.sort()` with key, but after inserting the elements of `list2` to `list1`. After all, OP wants to modify the list, which might be referred to in other places.

Comment: `Won't this do?` should only be used as a rhetoric question when you're sure it works. Otherwise, it should be a comment ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.. the problem is that some x.date are None and I don't want to change their indexes . I updated my post

Answer (score 2):

To return a new sorted list, you should use the sorted() built-in function:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list1 + list2, key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)
```

Comment: `true` doesn't exist in Python. Also : you don't need `reverse` here.

Comment: @tobias_k: Because it's been copy-pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects

Comment: indeed you don't need reverse, however, my intention is to show the possibility of reversing the order, @EricDuminil true this is not a simple paste it takes skill and deep understanding to understand the question, otherwise, i wouldn't modify x.date

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.. the problem is that some x.date are None and I don't want to change their indexes . I updated my post