# how to sort JSON float data before printing out

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to get data in JSON file, but before I print out, I want to sort the `money`. This is my code

```
with open("cash.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for c in data['NotAdmin']:
        a_new_list = sorted(c["money"])
        print(a_new_list)
```

This is what is inside my `cash.json` file

```
{
    "NotAdmin": [
        {
            "money": 200.0,
            "name": "Sam",
            "password": "1234"
        }, {
            "money": 150.0,
            "name": "Jasmin",
            "password": "1573"
        }, {
            "money": 100.0,
            "name": "Ali",
            "password": "1856"
        }
    ],
    "admin": [
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "password": "6767"
        }, {
            "name": "Eva",
            "password": "2222"
        }
    ]
}
```

Im keep getting this error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the `TypeError` is that you were iterating through the `dictionaries` in the `NotAdmin` `list` and trying to apply to the `sorted` functions to the `money` attributes. This will obviously fail as you are trying to "sort" a `float`(?).

So, the way the `sorted` (or `sort` function which modifies the `iterable` in place) works is to take an `iterable` and apply an "evaluation" function to each element, in order to sort them. This function can either be passed in under the `key` parameter, or if not passed in, Python will automatically decide how to sort the elements.

To apply this to our code, we want to take the `data["NotAdmin"]` list and apply the `.sort` method with a `key` to select the `money` attribute of each of the dictionaries. We can do this with an (anonymous) `lambda` function.

So, here is the full code:

```
with open("cash.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data["NotAdmin"].sort(key = lambda d: d["money"])
    print(data)
```

output:

```
{'admin': [{'password': '6767', 'name': 'Adam'}, {'password': '2222', 'name': 'Eva'}], 'NotAdmin': [{'password': '1856', 'money': 100.0, 'name': 'Ali'}, {'password': '1573', 'money': 150.0, 'name': 'Jasmin'}, {'password': '1234', 'money': 200.0, 'name': 'Sam'}]}
```

---

And also, if you want to have the elements in *descending* order, then we can take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and see that we can set the `reverse` flag to `True`.

Which would just change the line to:

```
...
    ...
    data["NotAdmin"].sort(key = lambda d: d["money"], reverse = True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

```
with open("cash.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    a_new_list = sorted(data['NotAdmin'], key=lambda k: k['money'])
    print(a_new_list)
```

By doing `sorted(c["money"])`, you want to sort one `float`, the `money` of the dictionary `c`, which is not possible, nor what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with open("cash.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
   data = json.load(f)
   new_data = {a:sorted(b, key=lambda x:x['money']) if all('money' in c for c in b) else b for a, b in data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'NotAdmin': [{'money': 100.0, 'password': '1856', 'name': 'Ali'}, {'money': 150.0, 'password': '1573', 'name': 'Jasmin'}, {'money': 200.0, 'password': '1234', 'name': 'Sam'}], 'admin': [{'password': '6767', 'name': 'Adam'}, {'password': '2222', 'name': 'Eva'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is due to its definition

```
sorted??
Docstring: sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

To tackle your problem, you need to sort array object using their attributes, example

```
with open("cash.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for c in data['NotAdmin']:
        a_new_list = sorted(c, key=lambda x: x['money'], reverse=True)
        print(a_new_list)
```

see more: [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: this is close to what I'm looking for, but there is an error with this TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is one line solution , You can try

Approach is , first check if key is `'NotAdmin'` and then sorted key is `'money'`

```
import json
print([sorted(value, key=lambda x: x['money']) for key,value in json.loads(open('data.json','r').read()).items() if key=='NotAdmin'])
```

output:

```
[[{'name': 'Ali', 'money': 100.0, 'password': '1856'}, {'name': 'Jasmin', 'money': 150.0, 'password': '1573'}, {'name': 'Sam', 'money': 200.0, 'password': '1234'}]]
```