# Sorting a list of objects by a string attribute while ignoring case in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I was able to sort a list of objects by a string attribute using this excellent post:

[How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

However, I also need the sort to ignore case when alphabetizing. Suppose I had a list of objects that each had an attribute "Name":

```
class MyObject (object):
   def __init__(self):
      MyObject.Name = None

itemsList = []

object1 = MyObject()
object1.Name = "Orange"
itemsList.append(object1)

object2 = MyObject()
object2.Name = "apple"
itemsList.append(object2)

object3 = MyObject()
object3.Name = "Banana"
itemsList.append(object3)
```

I can sort them like this:

```
itemsList.sort(key=lambda item : item.Name)
```

But how do I also ignore case? I tried throwing `lower` onto `Name` at that last line but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you throw `lower` onto `Name`, or `lower()`? The latter should work.

Comment: @tobias_k  Ah, you are correct. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer is that trivial, feel free to delete.

Comment: Be careful.  In your `__init__` method you're actually defining a class-level attribute instead of an instance attribute.  You just happen to assign to an instance attribute when you do `instance.Name = ...`.  If you try to do this with mutable objects, your code will display some very add behaviour.  You should assign instance attributes in `__init__` using `self`: `self.name = None`

Comment: Also, it's `self.Name = None`, not `MyObject.Name = None`, and it's conventional to use lowercase-with-underscore attribute names in Python.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, compare the strings after mapping them to lower case letters:

```
itemsList.sort(key=lambda item : item.Name.lower())
```