# Sorting tuples with dynamic values and length

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort numerical tuples by two arguments:

- first argument, lenght of the tuple: the smaller the tuple, the better;
- second argument, the n-th value of the tuple: if two tuples have the same lenght, then they should be ordered by the first numerical value by which they differ

For example, let's say we have these four tuples:

```
    a = (2, 5)           # len(a) == 2
    b = (2, 5, 3)        # len(b) == 3
    c = (2, 4, 3)        # len(c) == 3
    d = (1, 4, 4, 8)     # len(d) == 4
```

The result I'm willing to obtain is a function that will help me sort these tuples so that:

- a is the first tuple (the smallest one)
- b and c follows (the middle ones)
- d is the last tuple (the longest one)
- since b and c both get the same lenght, they shall be ordered so that c comes before b, because while their first value is the same, c's second values is smaller than b's

Therefore, the four tuples above should be listed as [a, c, b, d].

Question is: how do I do it, knowing that the tuples have no fixed length, and they might differ at any value from the first to the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort tuples with... tuples:

```
res = sorted([a, b, c, d], key=lambda x: (len(x), x))

# [(2, 5), (2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 3), (1, 4, 4, 8)]
```

The key is the `key` argument, which utilises an anonymous (`lambda`) function. Python sorts tuples by element. So the first element `len(x)` gives priority to length of tuple. The second element `x` gives secondary importance to sorting by the tuple itself, which itself is performed element-wise.

Comment: Oh you fast, I was somewhere else, vn

Comment: Alright, that works wonderfully! Thanks!
Now, if I may ask again: what if I had to sort for a certain attribute of an object, instead of the numeric value?
I mean, what if I had a = (Obj(id=2), Obj(id=5)), b = (Obj(id=2), Obj(id=5), Obj(id=3)), and so on, and I wanted them to be ordered as above?

Comment: See [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)