# Sorting dict() on field of class

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary with objects as values.  These objects are instances of the following class:

```
Class A():

    def __init__(self, x=''):
        self.x = x
        self.count = 0
```

The dictionary entries will therefore be of the form: `{'some_key', instance_of_class_A}`

Now, I would like to sort the dictionary on the the value of A.count within the instance_of_A.

I have failed to find an answer to this through numerous searches so am hoping someone has solved this before!
Thanks
P.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the dictionary"? Dictionaries are inherently unordered, even in Python 3.7, where the *iteration* order is guaranteed to match the order in which the keys were inserted.

Comment: I understand that yes, but I would like to order the dictionary.  And I need this ordering to be based on the value of the object field.

Comment: `{'some_key', instance_of_class_A}` does not look like a dictionary - do you mean `{'some_key': instance_of_class_A}` and are these dictionary entries in a list? can you show an example? also, please include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the values of a dictionary, you can do the following:

```
sorted_values = sorted(dict.values(), key=lambda x: x.count)
```

I do not see the need for sorting an entire dictionary, however. If the key value can hold a list of `A` objects and you want to sort that:

```
dict[key] = sorted(dict[key], key=lambda x: x.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a version of Python that provides for guaranteed ordering, you need to create a new dict, inserting the elements in the proper order.

```
old_dict = { ... }
new_dict = dict(sorted(old_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].count))
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is only guaranteed on 3.7+, but also works on 3.5 and 3.6 as the result of an implementation detail. This difference means that on non-CPython implementations of 3.5 and 3.6 this may not work.

Comment: Does it work in CPython 3.5? I thought that implementation wasn't added until 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

While dictionaries are insertion-ordered in Python 3.6 (as an implementation detail) and officially in 3.7+, for a robust ordered dictionary use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].count))
```

`OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, so you should lose no functionality.

If such an ordering is *natural* or *typical* to your class objects, consider defining `__eq__` and `__lt__` methods to your class [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731059/9209546) and then use:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))  # functional equivalent
```