# Customized sort on list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, oop

I have list of objects like

```
actors = [Person('Raj' ,'Hindi'),
          Person('John',  'English'),
          Person('Michael' 'Marathi'),
          Person('Terry','Hindi'),
          Person('Terry', 'Telugu')]
```

I want to sort this list of peoples depending on their mother tongue. In sequence Marathi, English, Hindi, Telugu. Means i want to sort objects in customized logic rather than in ascending or descending order.

I am using python 3.7.  Could you please help me how can this be done ?

Comment: What is the Person class? How do we access the `language` from an instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
sorted(actors, key = lambda x: mothertongue_list.index(x.tongue))
```

If we have that you can get mothertongue of `Person` by `tongue` and `mothertongue_list` is a list ordered as you want.

Comment: Probably better to create a dict `{tongue: index}` and than lookup the index in that dict instead of using `index`. Otherwise fine.

Comment: @tobias_k why `dict` instead of `list.index`? Any particular reason?

Comment: @Mortz, `list.index` has O(n) complexity, `dict.get` or `dict.__getitem__` has O(1) time complexity.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thanks. Does this have to do with the fact that a dict is a hash table?

Comment: @Mortz, Yes, exactly. Hashing enables O(1) lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any concept of comparator  in Python like we have in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

Answer (score 3):

Create a priority mapping of languages first:

```
priority_map = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(('Marathi', 'English', 'Hindi', 'Telugu'))}
```

Then use `sorted` with a custom key:

```
res = sorted(actors, key=lambda x: priority_map[x.tongue])
```

Alternatively, if applicable, make sorting a property of your class, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731059/9209546).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any concept of comparator  in Python like we have in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

Comment: @Shirish, Don't believe so, the closest you'll find is probably [this OOP approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731059/9209546).