# How to sort a list using a key in python

Tags: python

I have a list of words:

```
words = ['miel', 'extraterrestre', 'al', 'automovil', 'auto', 'revestir']
```

I want to sort this list using custom alphabet *(it contains 26 letters of the alphabet but ordered in a different way)*:

```
g = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
```

Expected result:

```
['revestir', 'miel', 'extraterrestre', 'auto', 'automovil', 'al']
```

Comment: use the default key and the reverse parameter - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort...i think automovil will come before auto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: Is `g` always the reversed normal alphabet, or do you need a solution for other orders as well?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is important and your list of words is even moderately long, you are probably better off making a lookup rather than searching for the index of each character for each word.

You can use the string function `translate()` and `maketrans()` to create a fast way of converting the input strings to a translation for sorting.

For example:

```
# make translation table 
trans = str.maketrans(g, "".join(sorted(g))) 

# translate words works like:
"revestir".translate(trans)   # 'ivevhgri'

# sort with it:
sorted(l, key=lambda word: word.translate(trans))

# ['revestir', 'miel', 'extraterrestre', 'auto', 'automovil', 'al']
```

This also has the benefit of being resilient to errors if there are characters in your strings that are not in your alphabet, which `index()` will choke on. They just get passed through, like:

```
"reve*stir".translate(trans)
# 'ivev*hgri'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` and pass as a `key` lambda function which converts your string into a list of indexes of each char of this string in your custom alphabet:

```
words = ['miel', 'extraterrestre', 'al', 'automovil', 'auto', 'revestir']
g = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
sorted_words = sorted(words, key=lambda w: [g.index(c) for c in w])
```

**P.S.** This is simplest but definitely not fastest solution, so **if your input list is quite big you should consider using solutions from other answers**.

Comment: g.index(c) is very slow for large inputs

Comment: @MohammedKhalid, it wasn't my goal to write fastest solution.

Comment: @MohammedKhalid How much "very slow"? And "large" in what way?

Comment: @HeapOverflow, I think, few hundred thousands of strings would be enough to feel the difference.

Comment: @OlvinRoght See a difference? Sure. But "very slow"? I just tested with 500,000 random strings of length 7. Your solution took 2.15 seconds, Mohammed's took 1.43 seconds. If that's enough to call a solution "very slow", then Mohammed's is also very slow, as Mark's only took 0.64 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient solution, instead of indexing for every letter would be to build a dictionary beforehand and use the `get` function which is `O(1)` for every letter in the word.

```
pos_map = {}
for idx, letter in enumerate(g):
    pos_map[letter] = idx

def key(item):
    return [pos_map.get(c) for c in item]

sorted(words, key=key)
['revestir', 'miel', 'extraterrestre', 'auto', 'automovil', 'al']
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than the other solution that also does this and more efficient than the `translate` solution?

Comment: more efficient than indexing, which I explicitly state

Comment: If speed is critical, I think translate will be faster than the dictionary lookups by a fair margin. But translate and maketrans are a little difficult to understand, so maybe not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
order={g[i]:i for i in range(len(g))}
sorted(words, key= lambda word:tuple([order[w] for w in word ]))
```