# Alphabetically sort a list of data frames by the names of these data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a long list of *named* Pandas data frames. My goal is to sort this list alphabetically by the names of the data frames. Here is a MWE:

```
import pandas as pd    
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(None)
df_1.name = 'a'
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(None)
df_2.name = 'b'
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(None)
df_3.name = 'c'
df_list = [df_2, df_1, df_3]
```

Now, my goal is to sort `df_list` such that I get a new list `[df_1, df_2, df_3]` reflecting the alphabetical order of the names of the data frames.

Comment: You can use `key` for the built-in `sorted`. `df_sorted = sorted(df_list, key=lambda x: x.name)`

Comment: This works as expected! If you make it a real answer, I accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With built-in `sorted`

```py
df_sorted = sorted(df_list, key=lambda x: x.name)
```