# How to sort a list of objects by a string attribute AND use the `key` parameter?

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a `list` of some objects by an attribute, but I also want to be able to specify a `key` when doing the sort (of those attributes).  I have seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/403426/13386979), which use the attribute to sort the objects, but I want to allow for other logic of sorting besides (for strings) just alphabetizing.  Here is an example class and sort function to show what I mean:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self): # for readability
        return 'Pet({})'.format(self.name)

def sort_pets(pets, reverse=False):
    pets.sort(reverse=reverse, key=lambda x : x.name)
```

So with this function, I can sort a list of `Pet` objects by their `name`:

```
>>> pets = [Pet(i) for i in ['Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch', 'Alice', 'Bozo Bob', 'Cy']]
>>> sort_pets(pets)
>>> print(pets)
[Pet(Alice), Pet(Bozo Bob), Pet(Cy), Pet(Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch)]
```

I can do so alphabetically or reverse alphabetically (using `reverse`).  But I want to have options for sorting the pets (by name) with different logic (like say the name length, number of spaces, last letter, etc.).  I can make a `key` parameter for `sort_pets`, but I can't pass it to the `key` parameter of `sort`, because it is already being used to access the `name` attribute.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by incorporating the `key` parameter from `sort_pets` into the `lambda` function when finding the attribute of each object:

```
def sort_pets(pets, reverse=False, key=None):
    if key is None:
        sortkey = lambda x : x.name
    else:
        sortkey = lambda x : key(x.name)
    pets.sort(reverse=reverse, key=sortkey)
```

So when a `key` is not passed to `sort_pets`, the objects are just sorted by their `name` attribute.  If one is passed, you apply that key to each `name` in order to build a new `lambda` key function.

Now you can use the `key` of `sort_pets` to sort the `Pet` objects as if you were just looking at the name:

```
pets = [Pet(i) for i in ['Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch', 'Alice', 'Bozo Bob', 'Cy']]
print(sort_pets(pets))  #no additional sorting
print(sort_pets(pets, key=lambda x : len(x))) #sort by number of characters
print(sort_pets(pets, key=lambda x : len(x.split(' ')[0]))) #sort by length of first name
print(sort_pets(pets, key = lambda x : x[-1])) #sort by last character
```

Output:

```
[Pet(Alice), Pet(Bozo Bob), Pet(Cy), Pet(Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch)]
[Pet(Cy), Pet(Alice), Pet(Bozo Bob), Pet(Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch)]
[Pet(Cy), Pet(Bozo Bob), Pet(Alice), Pet(Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch)]
[Pet(Bozo Bob), Pet(Alice), Pet(Dexter Lewis Cumberbatch), Pet(Cy)]
```