# sort a list of objects and re-index by attribute (fitness) value

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

In a genetic algorithm I have a list `indis` (population) of candidate solutions represented by objects of type `indi`. To make the selection straight forward, I want to sort these individuals by a fitness value.
Once sorted they should have a new index representing their fitness.

```
indi.getFitness()  # Returns the fitness.
indi.setId(index)  # sets the index
```

My initial approach is insufficient, as it doesn't include the sorting:

```
idx=0
for indi in self.indis: 
    indi.setId(idx)
    idx += 1
```

Question is: how can I sort by fitness and re-index to make the best solution index 0?

Comment: No, it can't.  `setId` alters its invoking object; a comprehension is intended to return a collection of values.  Writing a comprehension *specifically* for side effects is *uuuuglyy*.  Perhaps you want the `map` method -- see any tutorial on `map`.

Comment: You changed the question significantly after I posted my answer. That's not cool, although I'm not too bothered. If you want to change the scope, you should ask a new question instead, although it's already been asked: [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403421/4518341)

Comment: @wjandera, I'm sorry - they blocked me for the reason, that my questions weren't clear, so I tried the best to rephrase the question to be more specific - nevertheless your contribution was valuable thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lists come with the build-in sort method, one can use a lambda function calling the fitness method `getFitness()`. In this case it is important to use the `reverse=True` option as highest fitness mean lowest cost. The re-indexing is implemented as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296294/4518341) by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64296294/edit).

```
def sortByFitness(self):        # sorted population for single generation
    # highest fitness has lowest cost
    self.indis.sort(key=lambda x: x.getFitness(), reverse=True)
    for idx, indi in enumerate(self.indis):
        indi.setId(idx)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, [don't use a comprehension for side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4518341).

However, you can make it cleaner with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for idx, indi in enumerate(self.indis):
    indi.setId(idx)
```