# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'JpegImageFile' and 'JpegImageFile' error when ordering a list

Tags: python

I am trying to order a list of images by filename in order to make an animated gif, but I keep getting the same error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'JpegImageFile' and 'JpegImageFile'.

Here is the code and the names of the files I am trying to sort:

```
def gif_creator(filename, folder)
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(f"{folder}/{filename}*.JPG")]
    sorted(frames)
    frame_one = frames[0]
    frame_one.save(filename+".gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames, save_all=True, 
    duration=150, loop=0)
```

The names of the files are: PhotoIRBalkanf 1, PhotoIRBalkanf 2, PhotoIRBalkanf 3, PhotoIRBalkanf 4, PhotoIRBalkanf 5, PhotoIRBalkanf 6, PhotoIRBalkanf 7, PhotoIRBalkanf 8, PhotoIRBalkanf 9, PhotoIRBalkanf 10.

Comment: What is `JpegImageFile`? I guess it is returned by `Image.open(image)`, so what is `Image`? Why do you assume it defines an order between its instances?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: What are you expecting `sorted(frames)` to accomplish, anyway?  You're not doing anything with the sorted list it produces.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I agree, but when editing questions I err on the side of being conservative in what I remove. I did remove the chatter at the beginning though, so admittedly I should just have removed the image as well.

Comment: So you want to sort them... by filename? You might sort the names _before_ opening the files, then.

Comment: You can just sort the filenames beforehand: `paths = sorted(glob.glob(f"{folder}/{filename}*.JPG"))` and only then open the images: `frames = [Image.open(image) for image in paths]`. But you will then run into [the natural sorting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort).

Comment: Wrt, what @jasonharper said above -- you should use `sort()`, not `sorted()`, if you expect it to change the list in-place. `sorted()` returns a new list, it doesn't change the original one it was called on.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import os
...
frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(f"{folder}/{filename}*.JPG")]
frames = sorted(frames, key = lambda f: int(os.path.basename(f.filename).split('.')[0].split(' ')[1]))
```

When your frame list contains only Image instances, you cannot sort it without a key as Python doesn't know how to sort. Also, sorted is not in place so you need to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: They're all in the same folder, so why bother to isolate only the filename during the sort operation?

Comment: Also, this assumes that you're on a platform where `os.path.sep` is `/`; that isn't true everywhere.

Comment: Also this assumes that `f` has a `filename` attribute...

Comment: The last comments are both true but the person who asked used `/` and the Image has a filename when it is loaded from the disk.

Comment: Python translates `/` to a backslash when it's used as part of a path on Windows, so it may or may not _stay_ a `/`.

Comment: How do you know what `Image` is?

Comment: I can't know with full confidence but I'm pretty sure that it's a Pillow Image.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast responses. It's the first time I am asking and I am gladly surprised by the community

Comment: I get that error when running the code - IndexError: list index out of range but have no clue why it is giving it, to my knowledge it should work fine

Comment: Is there really a space in the filename? For example `PhotoIRBalkanf 3`?

Comment: Yes but I apply the same logic to another set of pictures  I think it will be the easiest if you see the code. I will post it as an answer. @Leonard

Comment: Please don't post questions as an answer, append it to the original question or ask a new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `sorted()` around the `glob.glob()`, *before* you call `Image.open()`. Then you only need to worry about whether filenames can be sorted, not whether images can.

```
def gif_creator(filename, folder)
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in sorted(glob.glob(f"{folder}/{filename}*.JPG"))]
    frame_one = frames[0]
    frame_one.save(filename+".gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames, save_all=True, 
                   duration=150, loop=0)
```

Mind, if you want `10` to come after `9`, then you'll need to sort on the trailing integer, instead of on the string. That might look like:

```
import re

def sortKey(filename):
  """Return a tuple consisting of an integer formed by extracting all numbers
     from a filename, with the original filename itself as the second entry."""
  numbers = re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', filename)
  return (int(numbers or 0), filename)

def gif_creator(filename, folder)
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in sorted(glob.glob(f"{folder}/{filename}*.JPG", key=sortKey))]
    frame_one = frames[0]
    frame_one.save(filename+".gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames, save_all=True, 
                   duration=150, loop=0)
```

Comment: This sorts somehow but probably not as intended (if 1,2,3,..,10 is intended). Yours will return (1, 10, 2, ..., 9).

Comment: @Leonard, yup, had an edit underway to fix that as you were commenting.

Comment: I like your method and thanks for the response I learned a lot

Comment: One more question. I haven't worked with this library - what's the name for the pip install?

Comment: @Charles Duffy and one more question for your logic. The sortKey function returns a tuple only for one filename that you then put in the glob. How does this help you with the sorting?

Comment: @GornaOryahovica, what do you mean "this library"? `re` comes with Python. It doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: @GornaOryahovica, As for the logic, `sorted()` calls the `key` function over and over, once per glob result. So _first_ `glob.glob()` is called, _then_ `sorted()` gets the sort keys for each glob result (each of which is a tuple), and sorts the items by those keys.