# Need to sort this by the value but move the 0 to the end

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

It currently looks like this unsorted.

```
[('391', '0'), ('411', '0.00'), ('174', '4'), ('734', '8.753'),('512', '6.3'),('700', '5.34'),]
```

I need to make it look like this if possible.

```
[('174', '4'),('700', '5.34'),('512', '6.3'),('734', '8.753'),('391', '0'),('411', '0.00')]
```

Comment: How is that sorted? Which logic did you apply?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: This data would be *vastly* easier to work with if you had actual numbers rather than strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `.sort()` method, first sorting normally, then sorting so that values equal to 0 are moved to the end.

```py
my_list = [('391', '0'), ('411', '0.00'), ('174', '4'), ('734', '8.753'),('512', '6.3'),('700', '5.34'),]
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]) == 0)
print(my_list)
# Output:
# [('174', '4'), ('700', '5.34'), ('512', '6.3'), ('734', '8.753'), ('391', '0'), ('411', '0.00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the key with a simple function:

```
>>> lst = [('391', '0'), ('411', '0.00'), ('174', '4'), ('734', '8.753'),('512', '6.3'),('700', '5.34'),]
>>> def get_key(x):
...     f = float(x[1])
...     return f if f else float('inf')
...
>>> sorted(lst, key=get_key)
[('174', '4'), ('700', '5.34'), ('512', '6.3'), ('734', '8.753'), ('391', '0'), ('411', '0.00')]
```