# sort card list by type first then by value?

Tags: python, sorting

How can I sort card list by type first then by value ?
for eg:
the player1 cards should be sorted like this:
2 clubs , 3 clubs , 6 clubs , 5 heart, 10 heart ....etc
I've read some search about lambda function but the result is not what I need any help?

```
from enum import Enum
import random

type=Enum('type','Heart Diamond Club Spade')
value=Enum('value','2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A')

class Card():
    def __init__(self,type,value) :
        self.card_type=type
        self.card_value=value

    def __str__(self) :
        txt=str(self.card_value.name)+' '+str(self.card_type.name)
        return txt

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and self.card_value==__o.card_value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)<int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __gt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)>int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def deal(deck,cardNum):
    cardlist=list()
    for i in range(cardNum):
        c=random.choice(deck)
        deck.remove(c)
        cardlist.append(c)
    #sorted(cardlist,key=lambda ) # My problem is here :(
    return cardlist
```

Comment: Would you try *natsort*?

Comment: "I've read some search about lambda function but the result is not what I need any help?" Well, after reading that, exactly what code did you try, and what was wrong with the result? What help do you need? What specifically did you not understand about it?

Comment: "#sorted(cardlist,key=lambda ) # My problem is here :( **if you implement `__lt__` etc. as you are trying**, all you need is `sorted(cardlist)`. If you get the wrong result, it is because those methods are wrong. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: __lt__ and __gt__ lacks logic for ordering based on "card type".

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421 answer your question?

Comment: Worth to read helpful information thanks sir  
Karl Knechtel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is *"human sort"?*
If not, please share what's the "inputs" looks like then.

Try this *natsort* lib:

```
>>>import natsort

>>>cards = " 2 clubs, 1 heart, 10 heart, 3 clubs, 9 clubs"

>>>natsort.natsorted(cards.split(','))
[' 1 heart', ' 2 clubs', ' 3 clubs', ' 9 clubs', ' 10 heart']
```

Comment: What's wrong is that 1) answers to the question should not be attempted yet, because it is not yet fully worked out (OP hasn't tested e.g. that `__lt__` etc. do what is intended in isolation, i.e. there is not yet proper debugging effort); b) there is no good reason to suggest a third-party library, since it looks like this is intended as either a debugging question or a conceptual question.

Comment: Yes. Sir,  I totally agreed with your point.  But the same standard is not applying to every single case?  Have seen so many respected/reputable guys just *do* it w/o checking the question. Even it's a very much FAQ common questions... then they got ++++ points.  Thanks.

Comment: So it's not really clear to me where is the *"borderline"*  - *to be or not to be*..  Hope someone can really *educate* me so that I can avoid this mistake in the future.  Thanks alot!