# Sorting class instances in a List

Tags: python, class, oop

How do I sort class instances in the list based on the `length` of the `pool`?

> Example:
> Current value in dictionary:
> {"Metal":[['A', 20, 50, 'Wide']], "Wood":[`['B', 50, 20, 'Thin']`, ['C', 30, 30, 'Wide']]

> Sorted value in dictionary:
> {"Metal":[['A', 20, 50, 'Wide']], "Wood":[['C', 30, 30, 'Wide'], `['B', 50, 20, 'Thin']`]

```
class PoolSet:
    def __init__ (self, ownerId, owner)
        self._ownerId = owner
        self._pools = {"Metal":[],"Wood":[]}

    #example of appending the Pool object into list based on the dictionary key
    self._pools["Metal"].append(Pool(label, length, width, grip))

    def sort(self):
       ????

class Pool:
    def __init__(self, label, length, width, grip):

    @property
    def label(self):
        return self._label

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Comment: You need to implement some magic methos for `Pool` class

Answer (score 4):

Both [`list.sort()` for in-place sorting](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [`sorted` for returning a new list](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted) accept a `key=` callable argument that accepts the object to be sorted and should return its "sort key".

```
self._pools["Metal"].sort(key=lambda pool: pool.length)
```