# How to order list of dictionaries in python by a given value in sub-list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I am having a list of dictionaries containing sub-list of dictionaries:

```py
x = [{'id': '1', 'employe_id': 15, 'name': 'John', 'columns': [{'Age': '22', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '2700', 'class': 'int'}]},
{'id': '2', 'employe_id': 11, 'name': 'Sara', 'columns': [{'Age': '19', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '1800', 'class': 'int'}]},
{'id': '3', 'employe_id': 12, 'name': 'Anna', 'columns': [{'Age': '34', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '3500', 'class': 'int'}]},
]
```

For examples sorting this list by Age or Salary

By Age I expect

```
x = [{'id': '2', 'employe_id': 11, 'name': 'Sara', 'columns': [{'Age': '19', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '1800', 'class': 'int'}]}, {'id': '1', 'employe_id': 15, 'name': 'John', 'columns': [{'Age': '22', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '2700', 'class': 'int'}]}, {'id': '3', 'employe_id': 17, 'name': 'Anna', 'columns': [{'Age': '34', 'class': 'int'}, {'Salary': '3500', 'class': 'int'}]}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of objects based on an attribute of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort Using lambda.

```py
x.sort(key=lambda i: int(i["columns"][0]["Age"]))
print(x)
```