# Sorting a csv file by column

Tags: python, file, sorting, csv

I want to sort the data in a csv file alphabetically according to the contents in the first column. For example, if the file contained:

```
city/month,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr

Melbourne,41.2,35.5,37.4,29.3

Brisbane,31.3,40.2,37.9,29

Darwin,34,34,33.2,34.5
```

it would be sorted as:

```
city/month,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr

Brisbane,31.3,40.2,37.9,29

Darwin,34,34,33.2,34.5

Melbourne,41.2,35.5,37.4,29.3
```

what I've done so far, sorts correctly but it doesn't return the answer correctly, instead of returning it in the table format, it returns everything as a list - any idea why that is?

```
import csv
import operator

def sort_records(csv_filename, new_filename):

  f = open(csv_filename)

  csv1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

  new_filename = sorted(csv1)

  return new_filename

  f.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089036/sorting-csv-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> import operator

>>> def sort_records(csv_filename, new_filename):
...     with open(csv_filename, 'r') as i, open(new_filename, 'w') as o:
...         reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter = ',')
...         writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
...         writer.writerow(next(reader)) # header row
...         writer.writerows(sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))

>>> sort_records('a.csv', 'b.csv')
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error from this:  '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'