# How to create a sorted representation of dictionary, using a custom comparator on tuple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a sorted representation of a dictionary with values (which are tuples), using with custom comparator on the values in Python 3, **in a generalised way**.

I have read these topics, but I'm still struggling:

[Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

[How to use a custom comparison function in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531952/how-to-use-a-custom-comparison-function-in-python-3)

As a **specific example**, one could consider the problem I'm trying to solve as, "get a list of products sorted by total cost, given a dictionary that contains the products (the key) a customer has in their checkout, along with the number and cost of each product (stored as a 2-tuple). In python 2, one could use something like this:

```
checkout_dict = {'Apples': (1, 3), 'Oranges': (3, 3), 'Grapes': (7, 1),
                 'Cheese': (10, 1), 'Crackers': (4, 4)}


from operator import itemgetter


def sort_dict(dict, comparison_func):
    return sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1),
                  cmp=comparison_func)


def cmp_total_cost(product_data_1, product_data_2):
    total_product_cost_1 = (product_data_1[0]) * (product_data_1[0])
    total_product_cost_2 = (product_data_2[0]) * (product_data_2[0])
    return total_product_cost_2 - total_product_cost_1


print sort_dict(checkout_dict, cmp_total_cost)
```

The expected output would look something like this:

```
[('Crackers', (4, 4)), ('Cheese', (10, 1)), ('Oranges', (3, 3)),
 ('Grapes', (7, 1)), ('Apples', (1, 3))]
```

However in Python 3, the `cmp` parameter for `sorted` was deprecated, and instead we need to include the behaviour as part of the `key` parameter.

I understand that we need to use something like like the [`cmp_to_key` function from the `functools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html), but I can't wrap my head around how I can keep everything generalised. I'm confused about how the `itemgetter(1)` can be combined with the `cmp_to_key` function and a custom comparison function.

Also, I understand that with the above example I could easily just loop over the dictionary first, and calculate the total costs, then do the sort, but I'm looking for a general solution I can apply for many different types of comparisons.

**Note**

I'd also like this to be as performant as possible. I found some info that using `operator.itemgetter` can really help speed things up:
[Sorting Dictionaries by Value in Python (improved?)](https://writeonly.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/sorting-dictionaries-by-value-in-python-improved/)

Comment: To make a long story short, what would be the expected output of `sorted(checkout_dict, key=magic_function)` ?

Comment: In the example given above, it would be a list of tuples `(product_name, (number_in_checkout, value))` ordered by whatever magic_function does.

Comment: But in what order?

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: Thanks for the help DeepSpace. Magic function might be the product of the number_in_checkout and the value, or it might be the quotient of them, or any other combination (value^number_in_checkout for example). I'm not really dealing with products in a basket.

Comment: What does "sorted representation" mean?

Comment: DeepSpace, itzMEonTV, martineau - expected output added to question.

Comment: @Jinglesting See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to get a list of tuples, ordered by the first element times the second element, this will do:

```
sorted(checkout_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0] * item[1][1])

#  [('Apples', (1, 3)), ('Grapes', (7, 1)), ('Oranges', (3, 3)), ('Cheese', (10, 1)),
#   ('Crackers', (4, 4))]

# or in the other way around
sorted(checkout_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0] * item[1][1], reverse=True)
# [('Crackers', (4, 4)), ('Cheese', (10, 1)), ('Oranges', (3, 3)), ('Grapes', (7, 1)), 
#  ('Apples', (1, 3))]
```

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace, I'm looking for a general way to do this for any cmp function that uses the values of the elements of the tuples, where I can just specify it as a parameter. Perhaps the example I gave was a bit too specific. This seems really easy in 2.x, but not sure in 3!

Comment: @Jinglesting I'm not sure I'm seeing the issue here to be honest. Instead of returning -1,0, 1 (for <, =, >) from `cmp` function you simply return the *actual* value to be compared from the `key` function. Python then figures  out how to compare that returned value with other values.

Comment: Also, the problem with the lambda function is all the overhead from the function calls (this is a problem in the 2.7 example I gave too). "operator.itemgetter" helps avoid these, but I'm not sure I can take advantage of this with my requirements. Could your solution be written in terms of "itemgetter"?

Comment: _simply return the actual value to be compared from the key function._
I don't think it's always that easy. Sometimes I will need to compare values from separate entries like this `(item2_val[0] * item1_val[1]) - (item1_val[0] * item2_val[1])` where items_val is a tuple value of an entry in the dict