# How to sort a python list using 2 conditional attributes

Tags: python, sorting

Lets say I want to sort a list that looks like this:

```
arr = ['45621', '78124', '24613']
```

The above list stores the IDs for various employees at a company. I don't want to sort based on the IDs alone, but based on attributes that correspond to the IDs, using the following dictionary:

```
employees = {
    '45621' : { 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 42 },
    '78124' : { 'rating' : 4, 'hours_worked' : 78 },
    '24613' : { 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 51 }
}
```

So its something like this: if an employee has a higher `rating`, his/her ID will come first. However, if 2 employees have the same `rating`, then we compare the `hours_worked`, and whoever has worked more will come before the other.

Right now, I am thinking about 2 different sorting methods: insertion, and merge. I edited a few code samples from the web, but I am struggling to compare the second condition, that is, when 2 ratings are equal for the algorithms. For instance, the edited versions of my insertion sort looks like this:

**InsertionSort**

```
def insertionSort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)): 
        key = employees[ arr[i] ]['rating']
        j = i-1
        # Falls apart after this part
        while j >=0 and key < arr[j] : 
            arr[j+1] = arr[j] 
            j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = key
```

The merge sort seems even more complex, but I am trying to at least understand one to get an idea.

Any help with these sorting methods will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Note: I don't want to use a built in sorting mechanism, as this is mainly for learning, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom comparison function in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531952/how-to-use-a-custom-comparison-function-in-python-3)

Comment: as a software architect your actions have direct influences on the world around you. you should not write software that sorts people according to how many hours they have worked and how their rating is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python `list.sort` or `sorted` based on a custom key:

```
arr = ['45621', '78124', '24613']

employees = {
    '45621' : { 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 42 },
    '78124' : { 'rating' : 4, 'hours_worked' : 78 },
    '24613' : { 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 51 }
}

arr.sort(key=lambda x: (employees[x]["rating"], employees[x]["hours_worked"]))
print(arr)
```

result:

```
['45621', '24613', '78124']
```

Also, since you need the ones with higher ranting first, you should reverse the order.

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (employees[x]["rating"], employees[x]["hours_worked"]), reverse=True)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ShinyPunctualMisrac)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it's better to organized data into a single list, you don't need 2 of them. Something like this:

```
employees = [
    {'user_id': '45621', 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 42 },
    {'user_id': '78124', 'rating' : 4, 'hours_worked' : 78 },
    {'user_id': '24613', 'rating' : 3, 'hours_worked' : 51 }]
```

after that you can use built-in `sort` function of list, combine with `operator.itemgetter` twice with corresponding keys you want.

Let say you value `rating` over `hours_worked`, you need to sort by the less important key first. `reverse=False` to put high value on top.

This way provide you more control, because sometime not both sort are in the same order. i.e: you want to sort `rating` descending but `hours_worked` ascending (user with high rating, but less work, mean more efficient)

```
import operator
employees.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('hours_worked'), reverse=True)
employees.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('rating'), reverse=True)
```

Result:

```
[{'user_id': '78124', 'rating': 4, 'hours_worked': 78},
 {'user_id': '24613', 'rating': 3, 'hours_worked': 51},
 {'user_id': '45621', 'rating': 3, 'hours_worked': 42}]
```

After sorting, you can get the `id` in order by a list comprehension

```
[u['user_id'] for u in employees]
```

Which gives:

```
['78124', '24613', '45621']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `sorted`:

```
arr=sorted(arr,key=lambda x: (employees[x]["rating"], employees[x]["hours_worked"]))
```

If need high to low on sorting:

```
arr=sorted(arr,key=lambda x: (employees[x]["rating"], employees[x]["hours_worked"]), reverse=True)
```