# sorting 2nd list in the same way 1nd list sorted

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I got to list `X, Y` of integers both size `N`. the vector `Y`,
corresponding to the `X` , (the xi label is yi)

Now I want to sort `X` and then sort `Y` in same order
if I done it in java I would override the sort method, but i am kind of new in python...
any nice method to do so?

Comment: What does "(*) such as the label of xi is yi" mean?

Comment: We need sample input and output data in order to be able to understand your problem. You also seem to have forgotten to post the code that's troubling you

Comment: You can override the sort function with the key argument.
Have a look at:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531952/how-to-use-a-custom-comparison-function-in-python-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip()` to bind each data point in `X` with its associated data point in `Y`. Then use `sorted()` and a list comprehension to read off the result:

```py
x = [3, 1, 2]
y = [5, 4, 6]

# Prints [4, 6, 5]
# These values are sorted in ascending order of corresponding x-value:
# 1 --> 4
# 2 --> 6
# 3 --> 5
result = [y_data for _, y_data in sorted(zip(x, y))]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean by "nice":

```
combo = sorted(zip(x,y))

sorted_x = [a for a,b in combo]
sorted_y = [b for a,b in combo]
```