# Python sorting str price with two decimal points

Tags: python, sorting

My goal: Sort a `list` of Products (`dict`) first by Price, then by Name.
My problem: `Str` values with numbers in them aren't sorted properly (AKA "Human sorting" or "Natural Sorting").

I found this function from a similar question:
[Python sorting list of dictionaries by multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143671/python-sorting-list-of-dictionaries-by-multiple-keys)

```
def multikeysort(items, columns):
    from operator import itemgetter
    comparers = [((itemgetter(col[1:].strip()), -1) if col.startswith('-') else
                  (itemgetter(col.strip()), 1)) for col in columns]
    def comparer(left, right):
        for fn, mult in comparers:
            result = cmp(fn(left), fn(right))
            if result:
                return mult * result
        else:
            return 0
    return sorted(items, cmp=comparer)
```

The problem is that my Prices are `str` type, like this:

```
products = [
    {'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '3000.00'},
    {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '100.10'},
    {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '20.00'},
    {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '5.05'},
    {'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
]
```

So they're getting sorted alphabetically, like this:

```
'100.10'
'20.10'
'3000.00'
'4.99'
'5.05'
```

Similarly, when I sort by name, I get this:

```
'Product 1'
'Product 15'
'Product 2'
'Product 200'
'Product 4'
```

The names should be listed in "human" order (1,2,15 instead of 1,15,2). Is it possible to fix this? I'm pretty new to python, so maybe I'm missing something vital. Thanks.

**EDIT**

More Info: I'm sending the list of products to a Django template, which requires the numbers to be properly formatted. If I float the prices and  then un-float them, I have to iterate through the list of products twice, which seems like overkill.

Comment: Do your prices have to be strings?  The best thing to do would be to cast them to floats

Comment: `int` type removes the decimal places ('1.00' = '1'), and `float` removes one decimal ('1.00' = '1.0') which doesn't look good in the shopping cart!

Answer (score 3):

Your sort function is overkill. Try this simple approach:

```
from pprint import pprint

products = [
    {'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '3000.00'},
    {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '100.10'},
    {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '20.00'},
    {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '5.05'},
    {'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
]

sorted_products = sorted(products, key=lambda x: (float(x['price']), x['name']))
pprint(sorted_products)
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '5.05'},
 {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '20.00'},
 {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '100.10'},
 {'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '3000.00'}]
```

The essence of my solution is to have the `key` function return a tuple of the sort conditions. Tuples always compare lexicographically, so the first item is the primary sort, the second is the secondary sort, and so on.

Comment: I like this! Only problem is that the sort function I posted allows for an unlimited amount of sort columns and negative sorting. Is it easy to allow for those two things using your method?

Comment: Also, this doesn't fix the second problem of sorting by 'name'.

Comment: Yes, `sorted()` supports an arbitrary number of columns and negative sorting.

Comment: What is the problem of sorting by `name`? In your question, you describe the result of sorting by name, but you don't describe what problem you perceive.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the name problem. They should be listed in "human" order (1,2,15 instead of 1,15,2).

Comment: What do we know about the format of the product names? Will they always start with the literal word "Product" followed by a space?

Comment: No, the user can write anything at all in there.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to parse the prices as floats (so you can sort them):

```
float("1.00")
# output: 1.0
```

Then output them with two decimal places:

```
"{:.2f}".format(1.0)
# output: "1.00"
```

Comment: If I do it this way then I need to iterate through all of the results after sorting them just to format it correctly. I'll review my code and see if I can minimize iteration. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try typecasting them to floats in the question and when you need to print 2 decimal places, you can easily format the output like so:

```
float_num = float("110.10")
print "{0:.2f}".format(float_num) # prints 110.10
```

Answer (score 0):

To break ties should there be any sorting the strings using the integer value from the product, you can return a tuple:

```
products = [
    {'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '2.99'},
    {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '4.99'},
    {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '4.99'},
    {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '9.99'},
    {'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
]

def key(x):
    p, i = x["name"].rsplit(None, 1)
    return float(x["price"]), p, int(i)

sorted_products = sorted(products, key=key)
```

Which would give you:

```
[{'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '2.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '9.99'}]
```

As opposed to:

```
[{'name': 'Product 200', 'price': '2.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 15', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 2', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 4', 'price': '4.99'},
 {'name': 'Product 1', 'price': '9.99'}]
```

using just `float(x['price']), x['name']`