# Python sorting by key, breaking ties

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key

```
original = ["aga", "aaa", "aba"]

dict = {
    "aba": 1,
    "aaa": 0,
    "aga": 1
}
```

I need to sort by dict values and tie breakers need to keep original order, how would I do that? Example very simplified.

I tried:

```
final = sorted(sorted(original, key=lambda x: (dict[x]), key=original.index))
```

Comment: why not using `collections.OrderedDict` directly?

Comment: I was under the impression that the built-in sort method _does_ preserve original order in the case of ties. `sorted(original, key=lambda x: (dict[x]))` gives `['aaa', 'aga', 'aba']`. Is that not what you want? If not, can you give the exact desired contents of `final`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sorting list of dictionaries by multiple keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143671/python-sorting-list-of-dictionaries-by-multiple-keys)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
Most notably, *research*.  "Python sort tutorial" would answer this for you much more effectively than we can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sort them based on their value in the dictionary. The original order will be preserved for ties:

```
final = sorted(original, key=dct.get)
print final
# ['aaa', 'aga', 'aba']
```

[*Timsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) - Python's standard sorting algorithm - is **stable**; items that compare equal retain their relative order.

On another note, do not use names like `dict` or `list` to avoid making builtins unusable later on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python don't store original order.  However, you could use an OrderedDict instead to maintain the order you wish:

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d['aba'] = 1
d['aaa'] = 0
d['aga'] = 1
print(d)
```