# How to do sorting in Python3 for a list dictionary inside?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of the dictionary as follows:

```
[{"A":5,"B":10},

{"A":6,"B":13},

{"A":10,"B":5}]
```

I want to this list in decending order on the value of `B`. The output should look like this:

```
[{"A":6,"B":13},

{"A":5,"B":10},

{"A":10,"B":5}]
```

How to do that?

Comment: I think this URL can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143671/how-to-sort-objects-by-multiple-keys-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

You can sort lists by the results of applying a function to each element: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#sorted

```
>>> data = [{"A":5,"B":10},
...     {"A":6,"B":13},
...     {"A":10,"B":5}]
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda dct: dct["B"], reverse=True)
[{'A': 6, 'B': 13}, {'A': 5, 'B': 10}, {'A': 10, 'B': 5}]
```