# Sort the list and element of the list is tuple but I have sort the array with both both the element

Tags: python

List

```
[(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)]
```

I want to sort the list with first element as max ie 4  but sort the second element with min first ie 5.
Output be like

```
[(4,5),(4,6),(3,4)]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want a answer in python?

Comment: Use the "key" argument of "sort" and provide a key function that negates the first item of the tuple.

Comment: Yes @annes help me please

Comment: `sorted(your_list,key=lambda t:(-t[0],t[1]))`

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher if you write the code in python , it will be helpful to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort objects by multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143671/how-to-sort-objects-by-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```py
l = [(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)]

l = sorted(l, key= lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(4, 5), (4, 6), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = [(3,4),(4,6),(4,5)]

lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[(4, 5), (4, 6), (3, 4)]
```