# Popular data exchange format that preserves input order even to represent unordered/unused elements? 

Tags: python, json, serialization, yaml

I've recently built a django JSON field, YAML field, Python field to explore ways to store/edit arbitrarily complex hierarchies of data via a CMS.

JSON, YAML, and Python can all be human formatted to be intuitive, but as soon as I coerce the text to python and back, it creates a new object which doesn't have ordering.

**Is there a portable data scheme that transparently preserves input order even if the data isn't actually ordered simply to reconstruct the original input however "the humans" decided to build it?**

Take for example python/json:

```
[{ 
   'title': 'First Data Entry!', # intuitive to have certain elements at top
   'is_active': True, 
   'data': 'data here'
   'a_list': [1, 2, 3],
},
{ 
   'title': 'Some Data Entry Here!', 
   'is_active': False, 
   'data': 'data here'
   'a_list': [1, 2, 3],
}]
```

Or YAML:

[image]

I can set up my data in a way that's instantly recognizable to my eye e.g. titles as the first line by convention.

As soon as I parse this into a python object, modify it, and convert it to a YAML/JSON/Python again, I of course no longer have comments or the ordering.

I'm curious if this is a common issue or if this is a wheel I need to invent. 
It seems possible with `OrderedDict` and writing a serializer (which I've never done...).

My current solution is to use YAML as a raw text field which is readonly - it won't try to write python objects to YAML to preserve style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python folded style (`>`) scalars are not preserved, and neither is the ordering.

If you can live with dropping the folded style, you can use the python package¹ [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) which is a derivative of PyYAML and supports round trip preservation of comments and roundtrip **preservation of ordering of the keys of mappings**:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import ruamel.yaml

inp = """\
features:
  show: true
  items:
    - widget: full_width.html  # full width 1
      title: Some Title
      description: >
          Foobar.
      vimeo_id: 20913
      zoom_image: some_url.png
    - widget: 3x_container.html
      items:
          - widget: 3x.html
            title: Some Widget Title
            image: 'foobar.png'
            description: >
                Some Description.
          - widget: 3x.html
            title: Some new title here
            image: ajax_uploads/png1_2.png
            description: >
                Some Description.
"""

code = ruamel.yaml.load(inp, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)

res = ruamel.yaml.dump(code, Dumper= ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
print(res, end='')
```

with result:

```
features:
  show: true
  items:
  - widget: full_width.html    # full width 1
    title: Some Title
    description: 'Foobar.

      '
    vimeo_id: 20913
    zoom_image: some_url.png
  - widget: 3x_container.html
    items:
    - widget: 3x.html
      title: Some Widget Title
      image: foobar.png
      description: 'Some Description.

        '
    - widget: 3x.html
      title: Some new title here
      image: ajax_uploads/png1_2.png
      description: 'Some Description.

        '
```

Which is stable output after the first round-trip.

Instead of normal `list` and `dict` objects the `code` consists of wrapped versions² on which the comments attached.

¹ <sub>Install with `pip install ruamel.yaml`. Works on Python 2.6/2.7/3.3+</sub>

²  <sub>`ordereddict` isused in case of a mapping, to preserve ordering</sub>

Comment: This is awesome. I don't even use `YAML` these days.. but if I started to again, this is *exactly* what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, dictionaries have no ordering, thats ther reason of change of orders...

One possible way might be using sorting functions on the dictionary (and then transform it to a `OrderedDict`... Or maybe you do not even need `OrderedDict` at all). But that orders as ascending/descending, so it might not help...

Final solution might be looing all dictionary and picking the keys one by one as you wish, and put them to your `OrderedDict`

[Here is a good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157424/python-2-5-dictionary-2-key-sort) about dictionary ordering...